# PHP How to call parent::__call() and pass in the arguments

Tags: php

If I am overloading the `__call` method in a PHP class, how could I call the actual method if my code doesn't do something else? For example:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    if($name == 'tom')
    {
        $this->doName($name);
    }
    else
    {
        // Something here to carry on the __call maybe:
        // $this->$name($arguments);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the `$arguments` are passed through as an array, how could I continue to pass them through info `$this->$name($arg, $arg, $arg ...)` is there a right way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can call:

```
return parent::__call($name, $arguments);
```

Or am I misunderstanding what you're asking?

**Edit:**

And if you mean you want to call `$this->$name()` to try to trigger `parent::__call()`, it won't work.  You'll wind up in an infinite loop until the stack overflows and php crashes (in other words, it's bad)...

Comment: Heh! Totally never thought of that! :D

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
call_user_func_array("self::method", $parameters)
```

Answer (score 5):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php is what you are looking for.